# What is the return type of COUNT() in t-sql?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am creating some documentation where I need to specify the type of data that is should be returned from a stored procedure.

The example sproc that I am working from is returning an aggregate column - using COUNT(), for example;

```
DECLARE @mytable TABLE (Id BIGINT, [Description] nvarchar(max), GroupId INT)

INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES (1, 'Value 1.1', 1)
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES (2, 'Value 1.2', 1)
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES (3, 'Value 1.3', 1)
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES (4, 'Value 2.1', 2)
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES (5, 'Value 2.2', 2)
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES (6, 'Value 2.3', 2)

SELECT GroupId, Count(Id) as 'Count'
FROM @mytable
GROUP BY GroupId
```

What is the return type of COUNT()?

Comment: Did you check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)? It does tell you.

Comment: And when the documentation doesn't do it for you, `SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(<expression>, 'BaseType')` can tell you the type of any T-SQL expression at runtime. There's also `sys.sp_describe_first_result_set`.

Comment: like Jeroen already mentioned, try this `SELECT GroupId, Count(Id) as 'Count', SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(Count(Id), 'BaseType')`

Comment: Why the question? Did you encounter a problem or unexpected behaviour?

Comment: @Larnu - Thanks for the link to the correct documentation. I had searched by landed on other pages that didn't have the info.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I have added details on why I am asking this.

Comment: @MarkCooper in that case the documentation is the first place to look at.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - thanks this is really useful for the future.

Comment: @GuidoG - thanks, that is useful.

Comment: Be careful that a lot of T-SQL constructs can actually vary their output type based on their input type (though `COUNT` is not one of them), so don't use things like `SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY` as documented evidence of what they will always do. Fortunately we have the documentation for the documented evidence...

Comment: @Larnu, write up a nice answer and get a `Reversal` badge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have just pointed your arrow over the field.

[image: Example screen capture from SSMS]

Anyway, it obviously returns an int value.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, but according to the documentation link provided by @larnu in the comments the return type is bigint. However I'm interested to follow up about the "arrow over the field" - can you elaborate that? Which field, in which application are you refering? Thanks :-)

Comment: Thanks, so it looks like the result from the SSMS tooltip differs from the documentation :S

Comment: @MarkCooper: it does not. The docs clearly say that `COUNT()` returns `INT` and `COUNT_BIG()` returns `BIGINT`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert so it does! #skimReadingFail